# Не отображается контент slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

нужно чтобы при нажатии на одну из трёх ссылок появлялся слайдер с товарами.
на самом деле он появляется, например если нажать на ссылку "распродажа" а потом покликать в пустой области, где должен быть слайдер, то он появляется. Не получается решить эту проблему, возможно что-то не так в самом js коде

```
$('.tab__info').hide();
$('.tab__info:first-child').show();

$('.tabs__item').click(function(){
  $('.tab__info').hide();

  var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  $(activeTab).fadeIn();
  return false;

});
$('.tabs__text').slick({
  // vertical: true,
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true
});
```

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/aKGLyx

Хотя я пробовал вместо слик слайдера вставлять просто текст и всё было нормально, ничего не пропадало

Answer (score 3, accepted):

добавляем вызов слайдера с аргументом setPosition, для того чтобы slick-slider перерасчитал ширину слайдов. т.к. когда инициализируется slick-slider на вкладке с display:none; он принимает ширину контейнера за 0, соответственно ширина слайда = 0.

```
$('.tabs__item').click(function(){
  $('.tab__info').hide();


  var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  $(activeTab).fadeIn();


setTimeout(function () {
    $('.tabs__text').slick('setPosition');
}, 300);

  return false;

});
```

Comment: кстати заметил что если много раз кликать по ссылке, то контент пропадает. как это можно решить?

Comment: пропадает если кликнуть дважды в очень короткий промежуток времени... ширина слайда становится равной 0, можно попробовать сделать задержку между кликом и отрисовкой.   
setTimeout( function(){$('.tabs__text').slick('setPosition');  }, 300)

Comment: жаль, не помогло(

Comment: может есть ссылка на проект? посмотреть...

Comment: http://ivanovst.ru/projects/megamarket/
на скрине ниже в каком именно блоке данная проблема
http://prntscr.com/k0m8zn

Comment: Вы не в том месте применили setTimeout, я в ответе поправил